# Equal stacks:code not working for large input

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack

I have been trying this since a long time but the code for the following problem is giving me wrong answer.
**Problem Statement**:You have three stacks of cylinders where each cylinder has the same diameter, but they may vary in height. You can change the height of a stack by removing and discarding its topmost cylinder any number of times.

Find the maximum possible height of the stacks such that all of the stacks are exactly the same height. This means you must remove zero or more cylinders from the top of zero or more of the three stacks until they're all the same height, then print the height. The removals must be performed in such a way as to maximize the height.
**Explanation:**
See this image:                [Explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ush35.png<br)

**Sample Input**

5 3 4
3 2 1 1 1
4 3 2
1 1 4 1
**Sample Output**

5
**My algorithm** for this is:
**Step I**. get the 3 array and reverse them, create a new array out of an existing array with each element is sum of all the previous elements. eg: [3,2,1,1,1] -> [1,1,1,2,3] -> [1,2,3,5,8]
So the 3 new array formed would be [1,2,3,5,8] [2,5,9] [1,5,6,7] 
**Step II**. Take the smallest array  traverse the smallest array and search element in the other 2 array - if the element is existing in other 2 array, STOP there and return the number.
Eg. Here I start with element - 2 : Which is not existing in other 2 array. Next I start with element - 5 : it is existing in other 2 array.


My code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long h1,h2,h3;
    cin>>h1>>h2>>h3;
    long long a[h1],b[h2],c[h3];
    long long sum1=0,sum2=0,sum3=0;
    for(long long i=0;i<h1;i++){
        cin>>a[h1-i-1];
    }
    for(long long i=0;i<h2;i++){
            cin>>b[h2-i-1];
        }
    for(long long i=0;i<h3;i++){
            cin>>c[h3-i-1];
        }
    for(long long i=0;i<h1;i++){
            sum1=sum1+a[i];
            a[i]=sum1;
        }
    for(long long i=0;i<h2;i++){
                sum2=sum2+b[i];
                b[i]=sum2;
            }
    for(long long i=0;i<h3;i++){
                sum3=sum3+c[i];
                c[i]=sum3;
            }
     long long i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

        while (i < h1 && j < h2 && k < h3)
        {

             if (a[i] == b[j] && b[j] == c[k])
             {   cout << a[i] << " "; return 0;   }


             else if (a[i] < b[j])
                 i++;
             else if (b[j] < c[k])
                 j++;
             else 
                 k++;
        }
        cout<<0;

return 0;
}
```

What modification should I perform for the code to run for larger values of input?
This code gives wrong answer for some input.
Please help

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i have verified but found no error

Comment: ***i have verified but found no error*** You most likely (did that wrong then). Did you step line by line through the code looking at the variables at each step to figure out where the behavior differs from your expectation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should traverse your array's in while loop from high to low values. Because we need highest value.Hence update your code

```
 long long i = h1-1, j = h2-1, k = h3-1;

    while (i >-1 && j > -1 && k >-1)
    {

         if (a[i] == b[j] && b[j] == c[k])
         {   cout << a[i] << " "; return 0;   }


         else if (a[i] > b[j])
             i--;
         else if (b[j] > c[k])
             j--;
         else 
             k--;
    }
```